# How can I use html/javascript to make <a> link trigger an embedded flash object?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, object

Using HTML/Javascript I want to make an  link trigger a flash object that is normally triggered by clicking on the flash  itself.  The flash objects is actually the "Call Me Now" button from Google Voice which looks something like:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
  data="https://clients4.google.com/voice/embed/webCallButton" 
  width="230" height="85">
    <param name="movie" 
       value="https://clients4.google.com/voice/embed/webCallButton"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="FlashVars" />
</object>
```

When you click on the object the first time it brings up a set of fields to enter your phone number in to make the call.  So I want to be able to trigger that action by having a user click on a different  link (which would actually be the phone number that the widget would call.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ExternalInterface class http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html which allows two way communication between javascript and flash.